# Is there a WebView equivalent for desktop browsers?

Tags: java, javascript, html, iframe, webview

I'm looking for a way to place a webpage in an `iframe` like frame, where i can view `https://` webpages as well as pages that have JavaScript code...

This is easy to do with Android Java Applications: i just use a [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)...

However, i'm looking for a way to do this on a desktop browser, possibly using html & javascript... Is this possible?

Comment: your title and you text are discordant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `iframe` can load https in most modern browsers (IE is an exception if I am not wrong). Also I have tried iframe with javascript and it is also fine in Firefox and Chrome at least.

You can see both used [here](http://www.clevelandutilities.com/obppay.htm).

Comment: yes, this is true in some cases (When the page comes from the same URL domain)... but try loading pages not on your sites domain, such as facebook, gmail or even google in an iframe... some http pages don't even work... cross-site-scripting is a big no no and hence is impossible in iframes... A WebView in java is different as it is made using the webkit rendering engine to display webpages...

Comment: Hmm sorry it was not quite clear from your question you were particularly interested in cross domain frames. As far as frames are concerned the thing you need can not be done. I also have a feeling that as long as you serve a single page to browsers and frames are not the solution, there will not be any at all, but can not prove it 100%. After all you want to implement classic cross-site scripting, which shouldn't be allowed by modern browsers.